# Clases en Flask basadas en vistas y en tablas de Bases de datos?

Tags: html, python, base-de-datos, flask

Tengo una duda que me surgio con respecto a las clases en Flask, ya que me doy cuenta que hay dos tipos de clases que se pueden usar para cosas diferentes

Las clases basadas en vistas, un ejemplo seria esto

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(label='Username', validators=DataRequired())
    password = PasswordField(label='Password', validators=DataRequired())
    submit = SubmitField(label='Log in')
```

que podria pintar en el html las etiquetas con los campos a rellenar cuando se quiera iniciar sesion

y las clases o modelos basados en tablas de una Base de datos, que son creacion de tablas, con sus respectivos campos y requerimientos, un ejemplo

```
class Users(db.Model):   
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)                 
    username = db.Column(db.String(length = 30), nullable= False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(length= 40), nullable= False, unique= True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable = False)
    budget = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable= False, default= 1000)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='owned_user', lazy=True)
```

estoy en lo correcto, si hay alguien pudiera aclararme mejor esto ya que me confundi un poco, gracias

Answer (score 1):

En realidad ninguna de esas clases que mencionas forman parte de Flask en sentido estricto. Son proporcionadas por librerías *de terceros* que se integran con Flask, pero que sirven a propósitos diferentes.

El primer ejemplo (el que deriva de `FlaskForm`) es proporcionado por la biblioteca flask-wtf, y sirve para simplificar el manejo de formularios web (HTML)

El segundo ejemplo (el que deriva de `db.Model`) es proporcionado por SQLAlchemy, que es un ORM (Object-Relational-Mapping), lo cual es una herramienta para poder modelar como objetos las entidades que se van a guardar en una base de datos relacional, "ocultándote" si así lo deseas el uso del SQL en las consultas, y resolviendo automáticamente por ti esas consultas, los join, etc, proporcionando una interfaz de objetos "normales" con sus campos y atributos, en vez de la vista de tablas, ids, claves foráneas, etc. que realmente guarda la base de datos.

En ambos casos las clases sirven para modelar los datos que vas a intercambiar con otro programa. En el primer caso el otro programa es el navegador y los datos que te envía son los resultantes de un formulario, y el protocolo por el cual la comunicación tiene lugar es HTTP. En el segundo caso el otro programa es una base de datos, los datos son los resultados de las consultas, y el lenguaje para hablar con ellas es SQL. En ambos casos la implementación basada en objetos te evita tener que conocer los detalles del protocolo y formato usado en esas comunicaciones, y te da una interfaz de alto nivel, basada en objetos y propiedades.

Comment: buenisima explicacion! gracias